# Auto-correct highlighting instead of bolding

Tags: keyboard, gboard, user-interface, android-11, auto-correct

Running Android version 11, this change happened very recently with a new patch.  Now instead of autocorrect bolding the center word it will correct mine to, it highlights it. This is extremely distracting, as now I have a teal/blue box flashing, flashing, flashing in my peripheral vision as I'm typing. How can I make it stop highlighting and go back to its previous behavior?

Edit: I seem to be running gboard.

Comment: This behavior depends on the Keyboard app. I'd assume it's Gboard, since I also noticed it recently?

Comment: Oh yes, it does appear to be gboard. I don't know if that's the standard option, or if I should be trying a different keyboard or what.